# Calling a function from inside the Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a function from inside the Javascript constructor like this:

```
class Blockchain {

   constructor(genesisBlock) {

     this.blocks = []
     addBlock(genesisBlock)
   }

   addBlock(block) {

      if(this.blocks.length == 0) {
        block.previousHash = "0000000000000000"
      }
   }

}
```

I get the following:

```
addBlock is not defined
```

Comment: You have to call `this.addBlock(genesisBlock)`

Comment: Thanks KevBot. If you can post this as answer I can accept it :)

Comment: It's not just a function. It's a *method*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the method is a prototypical method, and needs to be called from the instance of the class (by using `this`):

```
...
constructor(genesisBlock) {
    this.blocks = []
    this.addBlock(genesisBlock)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

***Why you are getting this error?***

When you are calling addBlock function inside the constructor in a following manner

```
   constructor(genesisBlock) {

     this.blocks = []
     addBlock(genesisBlock)
   }
```

**`It is looking for a global function called addBlock`**.But it can't find any.That's why it throws you an error.Your addBlock is a method of Blockchain class.Instances of Blockchain class will inherit it when instantiated.So you need to invoke it with 'this.addBlock'

```
 constructor(genesisBlock) {

     this.blocks = []
     this.addBlock(genesisBlock)
   }
```